# Problem with deploying rails app to heroku while running "heroku create" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Has anyone seen this problem before?
When I try to run the command "heroku create", I get long error with directories related to ruby.

---

C:\Rails\Waterloop3>heroku create

Creating severe-samurai-489.... done

Created http://severe-samurai-489.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:severe-samurai-48
9.git

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:78:in ``': No such file or directory - git remote (Errno::ENOENT)

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/helpe
```

rs.rb:78:in `block in shell'

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:121:in `chdir'

    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:121:in `cd'

    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/helpe
```

rs.rb:78:in `shell'

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/comma
```

nds/app.rb:265:in `create_git_remote'

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/comma
```

nds/app.rb:49:in `create'

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/comma
```

nd.rb:48:in `run_internal'

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/comma
```

nd.rb:20:in `run'

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/bin/heroku:13:in
```

`'

```
    from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `load'

    from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please format the stack trace properly (select all of it and press Ctrl+K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.14.10/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:78:in ``': No such file or directory - git remote (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Says that the heroku gem is try to run git and can't find it. Do you have git installed and running from the command line? It is a requirement, since it is what Heroku uses to manage deployments.